# Asrock X570 CPU+DRAM red leds on

Tags: cpu, post, dram

After powerup the motherboard immediately lights up the CPU and DRAM leds, and the VGA and BOOT never does. The machine does not go any further than that in POST. No image. Moving the RAM pair did not help. Resocketing the CPU did not help.

CPU: Ryzen 3400G
DDR4 rams 2x16
Bios version 1.40

Comment: Downvoter, can you explain how this question should be improved?

Comment: This question is far too broad for us to successfuly answer in Stack Exchange's Q/A format. There is a distinct lack of debugging and research information. Please note that I am not the downvoter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I solved my problem myself. There were no methods I hadn't tried. Last time I wanted to check the connections, and I noticed that I made the connections of the front panel incorrectly. Corrected the connections and resolved the issue.